# angular http post not reaching the backend

Tags: angular, http-post, content-type

I'm trying to make a simple post request to a web-api controller, where in the body there is a string, not an object.I manage to call it from the postman with no problems and with the settings of:
The url is something like:
http:///api//?id=111
Body (raw) has a simple string, for example: "aaa", and it is defined as JSON.
This is my code (ignore typos - it was written by hand):
this is the web-api controller:

```
[Route("Update")]
[HttpPost]

public bool UpdateData([FromQuery] int id, [FromBody] string content)
{
    DoAomwthing();
}
```

This is my angular code:

```
updateData(id :number, content : string) : Observable<boolean>
{
    const httpOptions = 
    {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'}),
        params: new HttpParams().set('id', '1')
    }
        return this.httpClient.post<boolean>(<some base url> + 'UpdateData', content, httpOptions);
    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your content type is `application/json` but you're sending a string? I don't think you can post a string, shouldn't you be sending an object instead?, also I wouldn't put the id in the form of a query but as part of the route instead `[Route("Update/{id}")]` and then change the method to read  as `UpdateData([FromRoute] int id...`

Answer (score 0):

you had your return statement inside the HTTP options obj

```
updateData(id :number, content : string) : Observable<boolean>
{
    const httpOptions = 
    {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'}),
        params: new HttpParams().set('id', '1')
    }

     return this.httpClient.post<boolean>(<some base url> + '/UpdateData', content, httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: @krimov -Sorry, it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Found out the root cause - the content should have been convert to a json string, bacause this is how the content type is defined (although json is doing such a change in a regular string and not an object, but still)